# Calling a MVC action from Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, servicestack, restsharp

I understand I can use the `WebRequest` to call an action on a ASP.NET MVC site. Can I use a library such as RestSharp or ServiceStack? If the response is in JSON, is there a way to deserialize this into anonymous types using either of these libraries?

Comment: Yes. You can. So go try? Why you want to call a website from an API, though, I have no idea. Backwards.